# List all categories in gutenberg block

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm trying to create a custom gutenberg block, which lists the latest posts of a specific category. Therefore I need to list all categories in the block menu, so that the user can choose.
I tried to get the categories using

```
wp.data.select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords( 'taxonomy', 'category' )
```

But, unfortunately, this just results in an error in the editor: *This block has encountered an error and cannot be previewed.*

How can I get a list of all categories in a gutenberg block?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you provide more code surrounding how you have implemented this in your edit() function? Have you used the results of wp.data.select as the values of a SelectControl or other component?

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault. I had a typo in the code: I tried to get the name of the categories with category.title instead of category.name. 
But thank you for your help and sorry for the inconvenience.